# Does child class serialize parent class' members that aren't serializable?

Tags: java, class, fileoutputstream, serializable, notserializableexception

If class B extends class A, class B implements Serializable, and class A has a public static initialized variable that is not serializable... trying to write a class' B object with `writeObject()` method of `FileOutputStream`, will serialize the non-serializable inherited member from A for writing it in the file with the rest of the variables of class B or it will throw `NotSerializableException`?

Comment: Why don't you check the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html)?

Comment: Francisco, people answered your question. Then you pulled the rug out from under them by changing the question and invalidating them. That is *not* how we roll here.

Comment: Question rolled back. Create a new question :P

Comment: `FileOutputStream` doesn't have `writeObject`.

Answer (score 1):

This works because **static** fields aren't saved when you write your object over an output stream.

From the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/ObjectOutputStream.html):

> The default serialization mechanism for an object writes the class of
>   the object, the class signature, and the values of all non-transient
>   and non-static fields. References to other objects (except in
>   transient or static fields) cause those objects to be written also.
>   Multiple references to a single object are encoded using a reference
>   sharing mechanism so that graphs of objects can be restored to the
>   same shape as when the original was written.

Comment: sorry, I meant non static.. :S